# beginTransaction() Null Pointer?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, csv

So i am having trouble with the part of my code that imports a .csv file from my sdcard into an sqlite database in my app.  According to my LogCat my "db.beginTransaction();" line is failing due to null pointer?  I really dont know how to fix this issue and am hoping somebody would be kind enough to help me out!

Here is what my code looks like to import the csv file into the database:

```
@Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();


        FileReader fr;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File("mnt/sdcard/database/",
                    "fcmtest.csv"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Error("ERROR File Not Found");
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String data = "";
        String tableName ="MY_TABLE";
        String columns = "Serial Numbers,PartNumber,Result,Date,Time,Operator";
        String InsertString1 = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") values(";
        String InsertString2 = ");";

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((data = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(InsertString1);
                String[] sarray = data.split(",");
                sb.append("'" + sarray[0] + "',");
                sb.append(sarray[1] + "',");
                sb.append(sarray[2] + "',");
                sb.append(sarray[3] + "',");
                sb.append(sarray[4] + "',");
                sb.append(sarray[5] + "'");
                sb.append(InsertString2);
                db.execSQL(sb.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error IOException");
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();

    }
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
02-01 14:20:04.071: W/dalvikvm(7655): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41033930)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.magna.magna/com.magna.magna.FCM}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at com.magna.magna.FCM.onStart(FCM.java:56)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
02-01 14:20:04.071: E/AndroidRuntime(7655):     ... 11 more
```

at line (FCM.java:56)  is db.beginTransaction(); 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` on that line because `db` is `null`. You never initialize `db` in the code shown above. You fix it by assigning a non-`null` value to `db`.

Comment: "private SQLiteDatabase db;" is called at the top of the page, i forgot to put that into my post on here, sorry about that

Comment: @Hockeyman271: Newcomers to Java should learn Java before getting involved in Android development. Your `private SQLiteDatabase db` statement declares a variable; it does not initialize that variable.

Comment: That's not just Java, that's basic OO programming concepts, period. The syntax may be different but initializing variables is about as basic as it gets, language be damned.